# MongoDB C driver: how to use regex query collection?

Tags: c++, c, mongodb, mongodb-query

for example, In MySQL the query like this:

```
select name from test_tab where id = 1 and  name like 'test%';
```

I want to translate  this query in mongodb  by mongodb C driver, so I write the code like this, but all don't work(the searchDoc() function is okay.

```
string strName = "";
bson_t *cond = bson_new();
BSON_APPEND_INT32(cond, "id", 1);
if (strlen(name.c_str()) > 0)
{
    strName = "/^" + name + "/";
    bson_t *child;
    child = bson_new();
    bson_append_document_begin(cond, "name", -1, child);
    BSON_APPEND_UTF8(child, "$regex", strName.c_str());
    bson_append_document_end(cond, child);
}
mongoc_cursor_t *cursor(NULL);
int iRet = searchDoc("db", "test_tab", cond, cursor);
if (iRet < 0)
{
    bson_destroy(cond);
    mongoc_cursor_destroy(cursor);
    return -1;
}
```

and

```
string strName = "";
bson_t *cond = bson_new();
BSON_APPEND_INT32(cond, "id", 1);
if (strlen(name.c_str()) > 0)
{
    strName = "/^" + name + ".*/";
    BSON_APPEND_REGEX(cond, "name", strName.c_str(), "i");
}
mongoc_cursor_t *cursor(NULL);
int iRet = searchDoc("db", "test_tab", cond, cursor);
if (iRet < 0)
{
    bson_destroy(cond);
    mongoc_cursor_destroy(cursor);
    return -1;
}
```

How can I build the regex pattern to query record work okay? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I seach  this page: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-206, 
there is a important tips: "You do not need to include the forward-slash when building a regex."

so I delete the forward-slash, my code

```
 strName = "/^" + name + ".*/"; 
 BSON_APPEND_REGEX(cond, "name", strName.c_str(), "i");
```

change to

```
  strName = "/^" + name + ".*/";
  BSON_APPEND_REGEX(cond, "name", strName.c_str(), "i");
```

It can work. My problem has been solved.